# How to prevent REST Url from inspecting in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, web-hosting

**REST Url are explode in flutter web app as in attached image. Are there any ways to prevent from inspecting?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to hide the URL of an HTTP request from the browser client, but what kind of a problem does this cause to you?